# How to make code on RMI server accessible remotely?

Tags: java, rmi, distributed-computing

This may sound a little basic but I just started looking at Java's RMI and am wondering about it's possibilities.

From what I understand the RMI client uploads to the server objects for execution. In return the server I will give the result of that computation. This seems like a great thing, but could I also invoke classes already present on the server itself? For example, let's suppose each node in my system often needs to process the same large piece of code. Let's also suppose I have limited bandwidth and several nodes to upload my objects to. I may find it better to call methods from classes already on the server. Is this possible? If so how?

Answer (score 1):

RMI Client don't uploads object to RMI Server for execution, RMI Client "calls" methods available on RMI Server. So technically what you want to do is exactly what RMI does. This is the reason why it is called "Remote Method Invocation" i.e. methods that are available in classes on a remote machine.

Comment: That's what I read on the Oracle tutorials. The server implements 2 barebones interfaces that allow it to process a result. A Task is sent to the sever that contains a specific object. The server computes the result and sends it back to the client.

Comment: That's a *specific use* of RMI: specifically, a mobile agent. The general part is the part where the client uses the remote interface to call the remote method at the server.

Answer (score 0):

> How to make code on RMI server accessible remotely?

That's what RMI is *for.*

> From what I understand the RMI client uploads to the server objects for execution.

No. The server implements a remote interface; the client calls a method via that remote interface; the execution of the call happens at the server.

What you found is a *specific usage* of RMI: specifically, a mobile agent pattern. But the interface itself, via which the agent got transported to the server and the result returned: *that* is what RMI does.

> Could I also invoke classes already present on the server itself?

Yes, that's what RMI does.

> Is this possible? If so how?

Yes, via RMI.

I think you need to take another look at the tutorial.